# What should someone do when a partial fax is sent to IRS due to connection problem?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

My question is mainly about what should happen and how to deal with partially sent fax form? As a foreign owned US LLC should send 1120 + 5472 by fax to 855-887-7737

I did this for years no issue but this year while sending my first attempt failed due to a connection problem from the IRS fax side; only the first page of 1120 was sent to IRS!

I made a second attempt after 30 minutes it also failed giving me Status: Failed (No fax detected)

After 2 hours I made a third successful attempt and sent my 1120 + 5472 in full.

My question is can the partially sent form cause me issues? like IRS sending me penalty for incomplete form sent?

I tried to find clear instructions on how to deal with failed fax attempts didn't find any. Of course I keep proof of fax sent.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you keep the fax confirmation showing receipt and timestamp you should be good.

In general, I'd suggest to file via mail. Send the printed out return via registered mail to the address given [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i5472#en_US_202401_publink100074081).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just resubmit the whole thing, calling it an amended return.

Comment: No, don't do that. You can confirm they got it through the IRS account, if they didn't then what are you amending? If they did then nothing to amend.

Comment: I'm sure it wouldn't be the first time the original form got delayed in the mail and the amended gut there first, so I have to assume procedures are in place to handle that.

Comment: The thing with amendments is that you only send the deltas. So the procedure would be to either hold on to it for a while hoping the original shows up, or reject the amendment. Neither is what the OP wants.

Comment: Hmmm. When I've filed an amended return. I've sent the full replacement set of forms, and the IRS didn't complain. "If it happens, it must be possible"?